# GitHub API : create pull-request that already exists should not throw exception

Tags: exception, github, github-api, git-pull, pull-request

GitHub API

Attempting to create a pull-request on a branch where a pull-request already exists will throw `422 Unprocessable Entity`

Is it possible to instruct GitHub API to instead return success code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to instruct GitHub API to instead return success code ?

The GitHub API itself, no.
But your script could, on 422 error when creating a PR, then check if the PR exists already, and if yes, return a success code out of that PR creation function.

As the [OP BaltoStar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236694/baltostar) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257557/github-api-create-pull-request-that-already-exists-should-not-throw-exception/31260490#comment50529156_31260490):

> more simply just check the response error message and if matches text for PR already exists then return success code.

Comment: or more simply just check the response error message and if matches text for PR already exists then return success code

Comment: @BaltoStar good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.